# Regex: Match all combinations of 2 digits except for specified

Tags: regex

I need two regexes:

1. Match all two-digit combinations except for "00" (so 01, 02, ... 99 is fine)
2. Match all two-digit combinations except for "00" and "01" (so 02, 03, ... 99 is fine)

I tried with something like `^(00)([0-9][0-9])` for the first one, but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `(?<!\d)(?!0[01])\d{2}(?!\d)` will work more or less if you need to extract the two-digit chunks not enclosed with other digits from a larger string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Match all two-digit combinations except for "00" (so 01, 02, ... 99 is fine)

   ```
   ^(?!00)[0-9]{2}$
   ```
2. Match all two-digit combinations except for "00" and "01" (so 02, 03, ... 99 is fine)

   ```
   ^(?!0[10])[0-9]{2}$
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to do that without the "\d" operator? I need it for the JSON schema pattern, and apparently "\d" is not supported by the validators.

Comment: try `[0-9]` instead